# Why FtpClient opens a new command connection for each file download or upload

Tags: c#, ftp-client

I use System.Net.FtpClient https://netftp.codeplex.com/ to download files from an FTP server, but each time I call ftpClient.OpenRead, a new command connection is created instead of using the already open command connection, which slows down the download process. Why, and how to change that?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out you need to set ftpClient.EnableThreadSafeDataConnections to false.

Comment: You want to be careful with that, a bug was introduced in System.Net.FtpClient, see https://netftp.codeplex.com/workitem/403

I used a day to figure this problem out. Command responses from former command seems to appear in as response to the next. The only choice I had left, was to turn on EnableThreadSafeDataConnections again.